# How to find a counter example for non convexity?

Tags: functions, convex-optimization

Consider a simple function $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}, x,y \in (0,1]$, the Hessian is not positive semi definite and hence it is a non convex function. However, when we plot the function using Matlab/Maxima, it "appears" convex. For the sake of clarity we want to find points which violate the definition of convexity, in other words identify the region (in the plot) where the function is non-convex. Can you suggest a procedure to do the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hessian is $$\nabla^2 f(x) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -y^{-2} \\ -y^{-2} & 2xy^{-3} \end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{y^3}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -y \\ -y & 2x\end{bmatrix}.$$
For nonzero $y$, the determinant $-y^{-4}$ is strictly negative. This means that there must be exactly one positive eigenvalue and one negative eigenvalue. The function is nonconvex *over the entire domain*. Indeed, it is nonconvex at every point $(x,y)$, $y\neq 0$.

The function is affine for fixed $y$, and convex for fixed positive $x$. So it may be that when you look at the MATLAB plot you're seeing the convexity of these cross sections. At any given point, however, it is actually *concave* along the direction defined by the eigenvector corresponding to the negative eigenvalue.

I cannot tell you how many people I have encountered that insist that this function is convex for positive $y$! Good for you for not falling into that trap.

EDIT: That suggests a way to graphically demonstrate non-convexity, by the way. Pick a point, say $x$, and find the negative eigenvector, $v$, or at least a vector satisfying $v^T\nabla^2f(x) v<0$. Plot the function $g(t)=f(x+tv)$. It will be concave, probably visually so, at $t=0$.

EDIT 2: Here you go: $x=0.25+t$, $y=0.75\pm t$:
[image]

Comment: So actually no function $f(x,y)=x g(y)$ may be convex (given $g'(y) \neq 0$). Interesting. Thank you for the plot!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the plot and the procedure to graphically demonstrate the non convexity.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you only look at one quadrant of $f(x)=\frac{x}{y}$ then it appears to be convex but if you look at all the quadrants then you should see that its non-convex.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am not sure what you mean by all the quadrants. The domain of the function is $x,y \in (o,1]$, which is the first quadrant.

Answer (score -1):

If you write down the Hessian matrix you'll see that for $x,y\in (0,1]$ the Hessian is indeed positive semi-definite. This is call *conditional* positive semi-definiteness. You can see the Hessian as a matrix parametrized by $x$ and $y$: it is positive semi-definite depending on their values. Try to compute the eigen-values as a function of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: The Hessian is not conditional positive semi-definite. The determinant of the Hessian is $\frac{-1}{y^4}$.